# Filter Pandas Groupby monotonically

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a Dataframe of values like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([ [ 23, .30], [ 23, .29], [ 23, .33], [ 23, .29], [ 23, .31], [ 25, .31], [ 25, .32], [ 25, .22], [30, 0.9], [30, 0.91], [30, 0.92] ], columns=['Day', 'Rate'] )
```

I want to group by Day but only filter out the values that are strictly increasing. So for the above data frame, the answer would look like this:

```
ans = pd.DataFrame([ [ 23, .30], [ 23, .33], [ 25, .31], [ 25, .32], [30, 0.9], [30, 0.91], [30, 
0.92] ], columns=['Day', 'Rate'] )
```

In practice this dataframe can be very large (>10000 rows) so I want to avoid writing a custom apply on the group object. Is there a quick (efficient) way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THe new "Rate" can be obtained by `groupby-cummax`. Just replace Rate with the new values and drop duplicates. `.reset_index()` is optional.

```
df["Rate"] = df.groupby("Day").cummax()
df = df.drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
print(df)

   Day  Rate
0   23  0.30
1   23  0.33
2   25  0.31
3   25  0.32
4   30  0.90
5   30  0.91
6   30  0.92
```